# Window displayed but not the buttons

Tags: java, swing

I wrote this code to display a window with three buttons. However, the window appears but not the buttons. Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;



public class Test3 extends JFrame{


public Test3() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Exemple");
    JButton button1 = new JButton("Règles");
    button1.setBounds(100, 60, 100, 30);
    JButton button2 = new JButton("Jouer");
    JButton button3 = new JButton("Scores");
    JPanel pane1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    this.setVisible(true);

    pane1.add(button1);
    pane1.add(button2);
    pane1.add(button3);
    frame.getContentPane().add(pane1, BorderLayout.EAST);
    this.setVisible(true);
    setSize(800, 600);



}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test3 test3 = new Test3();
}

}
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this ?

Thanks for your help !

Agnès

Comment: Could you try with this.pack() ?

Comment: @damus4 On which instance of `JFrame` should the OP pack?

Comment: @ MadProgrammer It's my bad i dind't saw the all picture... so doing a pack() on the frame then setVisible on the frame and not this twice

Comment: @damus4 It's alright, my brain imploded while trying to read the code :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two windows...

```
public class Test3 extends JFrame{
    public Test3() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Exemple");
```

You're adding content to `frame`, but showing `Test3`...

As a general rule of thumb, you should avoid extending from top level containers like `JFrame` and instead, create an instance when you need it.  This unlocks you from a given implementation and allows you flexibility in deciding how you might re-use given components, as an example.

```
public class Test3 {
    public Test3() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Exemple");
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Règles");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Jouer");
        JButton button3 = new JButton("Scores");
        JPanel pane1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        pane1.add(button1);
        pane1.add(button2);
        pane1.add(button3);
        frame.getContentPane().add(pane1, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Runnable example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test3 {

    public Test3() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Exemple");
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Règles");
        button1.setBounds(100, 60, 100, 30);
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Jouer");
        JButton button3 = new JButton("Scores");
        JPanel pane1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        pane1.add(button1);
        pane1.add(button2);
        pane1.add(button3);
        frame.getContentPane().add(pane1, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                Test3 test3 = new Test3();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however, I have 2 errors: 
'Syntax error on tokens, ClassHeader expected instead' and 
'Syntax error on token "public", @ expected after this token'

Comment: for the line public Test3() {

Comment: @AgnèsMustar That's because it's just the constructor

Comment: It removes one of the `two` references to `JFrame` you have, resolving it so you only have one frame to which you add components to and to which is made visible...

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this, I have corrected

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;



public class Test3 extends JFrame{


public Test3() {

   super("Exemple");
    JButton button1 = new JButton("Règles");
    button1.setBounds(100, 60, 100, 30);
    JButton button2 = new JButton("Jouer");
    JButton button3 = new JButton("Scores");
    JPanel pane1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    this.setVisible(true);

    pane1.add(button1);
    pane1.add(button2);
    pane1.add(button3);
    getContentPane().add(pane1, BorderLayout.EAST);
    this.setVisible(true);
    setSize(800, 600);



}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test3 test3 = new Test3();
}

}
```

Comment: What have you corrected and why did you choose to correct it this way?  Why should the OP use your method of other methods?

Comment: OP needs to show window with three buttons.  So as he was extending jframe..it is better to use methods from super class rather creating new instance of jframe. Your answer was posted before my answer while I was typing. ..

Comment: Okay, don't tell me, tell the OP.  But IMHO, extending from `JFrame` is generally a bad idea

Comment: Can you give me the reason why it is bad? For eg. If you know android, A gui object extends Activitiy but I rarely see people using new Activity()

Comment: Swing is not Android and the means by which you can construct it are different.  You're not adding any new functionality to the frame, so extending it just locking you into an implementation which makes it really difficult to re-use the code.

Comment: Ok, I came to the point, but one thing, users can post many answers and OP can decide which is the best. And your implementation is better than mine. Thanks

Comment: What's "best" and the op "chooses" isn't always the something ;)